# Div positioned relative give min-width unless content is wider

Tags: html, css, width

I have a div position: relative (this shouldn't matter). I would like to ensure the width is a particular width unless the content is larger. I've tried min-width but it seems to be ignored. Setting the width explicitly also force line breaks when text content is wider than width.

```
<div style="padding-top:6px; max-height:40px;">
    <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="LAST NAME">
    <div id="lnameError" class="error-block">Please enter a valid last name</div>
</div>

.error-block {
    border: solid 1px #e60211;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 250px;    
    display:none;
    position: relative;
    left: 288px;
    top: -40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #e60211;
    font-family:MontrealTS-Regular;
    line-height:38px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right:12px;
}

$('#lname').focusout(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
            $(this).next().animate({
                opacity: "show"
            }, "slow", "jswing");
        }
    });
```

If i use display:inline-block the positioning and size is incorrect after the animate. If i put no display attribute value in the css and an opacity value of 0 in the css the block never shows.

Comment: did you try display:inline-block?

Comment: Can you share your code, including whatever your jquery is?

Comment: edited with additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your element have a default value of `display: block` which will take the whole width, you better to specify `display: inline-block;` or `display: table;`

```js
$('#lname').focusout(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
    $(this).next().fadeTo("slow", 1, function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.error-block {
  border: solid 1px #e60211;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  /* left: 288px; */
  /* top: -40px; */
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #e60211;
  font-family: MontrealTS-Regular;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding-top:6px; max-height:40px;">
  <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="LAST NAME">
  <div id="lnameError" class="error-block">Please enter a valid last name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using jquery animate opacity "show". Which i'm assuming animates to display:block. Do you have any suggestions on how i can keep using the animate but force the same width considerations?

Comment: hey thanks, appears to work but what is the mydiv css class used for?

Comment: @billyjean oh that one just remove it, i updated now